# String examples of regular expressions?

Tags: regex

My assignment states: "Give an example of a string represented by each of the following regular expressions."

I've managed to do all of them expect one:

```
[0-9]+ ((E|e) (\+|\-)? [0-9]+)?
```

I do not get what is meant by `(\+|\-)?` .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for the answer to a homework problem.

Comment: @zzzzBov actually I believe he simply asks what does `(+|-)?` mean. He doesn't explicitly ask for a canned solution.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski, he hasn't bothered to tag an appropriate language either, and a simple google search for regex syntax will result in the answer. I'm not inclined to keep this around.

Comment: `+` in a regex is a quantifier and has a special meaning. If you want to match the literal character `+`, you must escape it in the regex with a backslash. Strangely, `-` isn't a special character at all, has no special meaning but here it is escaped too (probably a mistake). In this case the backslash is simply ignored by the regex engine most of the time, so you can read it as: `(\+|-)?`

Comment: 42, 123e-4, 56E+7, 12e2, 156E46... backslash are here to consider + and - as  simple chars.

Answer (score 1):

Because both `+` and `-` are special characters in *regular expressions* they need to be *escaped* when matching them. So `\-` matches a `-` and `\+` matches a `+`. Also `?` makes the match optional.

Therefore:

```
(\+|\-)? matches either + or - or nothing at all
```

The `-` sign is not always special and apparently can be matched directly or in its escaped form.

**Example:** https://regex101.com/r/kP2tP8/1

Answer (score 0):

This simply means that a plus or minus sign is optional.

The parenthesis enclose the group and the question mark states that the preceding token (the one in the parenthesis) is optional.

So something valid could be

```
500 E + 44
```